# Burg will not detect grub on install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, burg

Ubuntu version: 16.04

Grub version: grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2

Computer: Acer Aspire S7 392

Dual booting: Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10
/boot/grub/device.map file not found
Result of sudo burg-install "(hd0)":

```
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/isw_cbiahjhdcc_Volume0p6.  Check your device.map.
Auto-detection of a filesystem module failed.
Please specify the module with the option `--modules' explicitly.
```

Grub works fine, loads on bootup and offers me Windows EFI boot loader or Ubuntu. I do not want to change to legacy boot loader as UEFI is much faster boot times in my experience.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Burg is no longer maintained and does not support UEFI.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, So if BURG is no longer maintained, is there any alternative that supports UEFI?